# Symfony 5.0.5 Custom logout. Multiple logout manually

Tags: logout, symfony5

Im using Symfony 5.0.5. This webapp have a backoffice for admins and other customer backoffice or customer informations for "customers"

Im have multiple login routes onto my app. Im trying to implemente multiple logout router because I need check or make some actions on each case

security.yaml

```
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
```

account.yaml

```
account_logout:
    path:     logout/comom
    controller: App\Controller\Security\SecurityController::logout
    methods: [GET]
account_customer_logout:
    path:     logout/customer
    controller: App\Controller\Security\SecurityController::logoutCustomer
    methods: [GET]
```

SecurityController.php

```
   public function logout()
    {
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
        $this->get('session')->invalidate();
        // some stuff
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl("account_login"));
    }

    public function logoutCustomer()
    {
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
        $this->get('session')->invalidate();
        // some stuff
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl("login_customer"));
    }
```

Any advice?

Comment: any advice on what exactly? Whta is it that bothers you exactly?

Comment: Thanks I found!! just change a param on security.yaml

Answer (score 1):

I found!!

just change anonymous to true

```
   firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
```